# message in div failed to fade in on refresh of the page while learning jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the HTML for the div i want to fadeIn
and the jQuery code for fading the text in the above div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#message').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Band Site| Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="band.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="message" style="display:none;">welcome to my website</div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does it show `#message` element ?

Comment: Does it fade in at all? 
If not, do you have some jquery errors in the console?

Comment: Open console and read your errors. (As you can see your code should work)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan — I guess you are right.. I had faced similar scenario earlier but failed to reproduce it :)

Comment: it shows the message element when i set to fast like in the above...but when i set to slow it totally disappears

Comment: console is showing the error...uncaught type error $(...).fadeIn() is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>.Can't make sense of it though

Comment: I've updated the snippet with full code sample. It works on my machine and when you click run

Answer (score 0):

I think fast is too fast. :) 
Try it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Band Site| Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="message" style="display:none;">welcome to my website</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#message').fadeIn(3000);
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've removed band.css (since I don't have that file) and I've put jquery code directly into `<script>` tag so everything is in one place.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working just fine. Instead of adding 'fast' use some duration.

**HTML**

```
<div id="message" style="display:none;">welcome to my website</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#message').fadeIn('8000');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/fjg86nap/)